# How to extract iOS system localizable strings?

Tags: ios, iphone, filesystems

I'm looking for system localizable strings because I would like to retrieve traduction of the push acceptance pop-up. 
After searching for a day, I can't find a way to access it via UIKit bundle for exemple.

Is there a way to extract the localizable iOS system strings ?

Answer (score 0):

Ok I've myself the solution.
I had to `jailbreak` my phone, extract the `SpringBoard.app` and extract text from `SpringBoard.strings` for all `.lproj` .